# Como pasar datos de un arreglo string a datetime en C# estos datos se tienen que guardar en un BD sql

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema estoy realizando una consulta a una BD en access y leo los datos y esos mismos datos los inserto a otra base de datos en sql server, el problema es que cuando quiero ingresar datos de tipo datetime, no me deja, he intentado con convert y Parse pero nu puedo necesito ayuda. estoy utilizando C#

```
        conexion.Open();
        con.Open();
        string consulta = "SELECT * FROM [Unit]";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(consulta, conexion);
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            string insertar = "insert into [Unit] " +
            "values ('" + Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]) + "', '" + reader[1] + "');";//el compo reader[1]es una fecha
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(insertar, con);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conexion.Close();
        con.Close();
```

ERRRor que me da es que nu puedo convertir un entero a datetime

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que contiene reader[0]? podrias mostrar que viene ahi?

Comment: Reader[0] contiene el campo uno de la tabla, estoy utilizando reader como un areglo y este lo quiero insertar en la base sql

Comment: Y ese campo contiene una fecha?

Answer (score 1):

Para poder insertar una fecha tienes que usar parametros

```
string consulta = "SELECT * FROM [Unit]";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(consulta, conexion);
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


string insertar = @"insert into [Unit] (nombrecampo1, nombrecampo2)
                    values (@param1, @param2)";
SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(insertar, con);
    
while (reader.Read())
{
    comando.Parameters.Clear();
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", reader[0].ToString());
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Convert.ToDateTime(reader[1]));
    
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

como observaras se usa la coleccion `Parameters` del `SqlCommand`

Cuando defines el insert indica los nombres de los campos, de esta forma defines el orden en que debe asignarse el parametro

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya me salio.